# Transpose of matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, compiler-errors, transpose

Im not sure whats wrong with my code but its does not give any output
it only takes input and after that my terminal ends the program
im  using ubunto linux .

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A[3][3];
    int B[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << "" << i << j << ": ";
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            B[j][i] = A[i][j];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << B[i][j];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://rextester.com/NMC31915). Your code works for me as written, and produces expected output.

Comment: "and after that my terminal ends the program" do you actually mean "the terminal closes and I cannot see the output" ?

Comment: [Don't get in the habit of `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/430766)

Comment: Your running code inside IDE? Sure you have selected the correct output terminal? Try to run the compiled binary from simple windows command line / bash, see if you can register any output you're expecting ;). If so, have a closer look at your IDE, probably start withe a new hello world and copy&paste your code if you have seen "Hello World" displayed on the IDE's console once.

Comment: @idclev463035818   i mean in terminal takes the input and after that it dont cout what its supposed to do ,the terminal ends the process after i give the input

Comment: I dont understand what that means "the terminal ends the process after i give the input" . The terminal stays open? Can you post the output you see in the terminal? (even if it is only `ij :` and your input)

Comment: @idclev463035818 
012
023
104
115
126
207
218
229
XPS-15-9550:~$